# Difference between free and billed apps

Tags: google-app-engine

Is any difference between billed and free apps other than quotas?
For example - billed apps run on more fast server.

Answer (score 1):

Except the [quotas and other things](http://cloud.google.com/pricing/) you can choose [faster instances](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings) when you are on billed account. But by default they are running on the same fronted class (F1).

Comment: Free apps don't have access to the edge cache either.